# Get char pointer in assembler function

Tags: c, linux, assembly

I need to get my char pointer and after that i print it on the screen to see if it works ok.
I read the text from a file and put in my char pointer (sizeof(char*) + filesize) + 1.. in the end i put the '\0'.
If i printf my char* its fine
Here is my asm code

```
; void processdata(char* filecontent);
section .text
    global processdata
    extern printf
section .data
FORMAT: db '%c', 10, 0 ; to break the line 10, 0
processdata:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, [ebp]
    push ebx
    push FORMAT
    call printf
    add esp, 8
```

when i run it i just see trash in my variable.

As violet said:

```
; void processdata(char* filecontent);
section .text
        [GLOBAL processdata] ;global processdata 
        extern printf
section .data
FORMAT: db '%c', 0
EQUAL: db "is equal", 10, 0
processdata:

    lea   esi,  [esp]
    mov   ebx,  FORMAT 
oook:   
    mov   eax,  [esi]
    push  eax
    push  ebx 
    call  printf
    inc   esi
    cmp  esi, 0x0
    jnz  oook
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting it to display? You're pushing `ebx` which is `[ebp]` on the stack and trying to display it as a `char`. I think that's the return address actually.

Comment: yes, how can i get the char pointer so i can print one by one.

Comment: i have a string ex "aaaaccccaaasss" so i call the processdata(processString) i want to get that in my assembler code and print the first char a so i can increment the pointer and keep printing the chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quote [demonofnight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109847/demonofnight)

> But if i need to increment, can i do that?

Using your original function arg of `char*` and your `%c` format, something like this:

```
    lea   esi,  [esp+4]
    mov   ebx,  FORMAT 
oook:   
    mov   eax,  [esi]
    push  eax
    push  ebx 
    call  printf
    inc   esi
    cmp  [esi], 0x0
    jnz  oook
```

[edit: ok sry, i hacked that quickly into some shenzi winOS inline `__asm` block]
here's a complete thing done in linux and nasm:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; blah.asm
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

        extern  printf


        SECTION .data                   ;local variables
        fmt: db "next char:%c", 10, 0   ;printf format, "\n",'0'


        SECTION .text                   ;hack in some codes XD
        global foo

foo:                                    ;foo entry
        push  ebp                       ;set up stack frame
        mov   ebp,esp

        mov   esi, [ebp+8]              ;load the input char array to the source index

oook:                                   ;loop while we have some chars
        push  dword [esi]               ;push next char addy in string to stack
        push  dword fmt                 ;push stored format string to stack

        call  printf

        add   esp, 8                    ;restore stack pointer 
        inc   esi                       ;iterate to next char
        cmp   byte [esi], 0             ;test for null terminator byte 
        jnz   oook

        mov   esp, ebp                  ;restore stack frame
        pop   ebp

        mov   eax,0                     ;return 0
        ret                             ;done
```

blah.c (that invokes the .asm foo) :

```
/*-----------------------------------------------
blah.c
invokes some asm foo
------------------------------------------------*/
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char*);

int main() {

    char sz[]={"oook\n"};
    foo(sz);

    return 0;
}
```

&here's the commandline stuff:

```
$ nasm -f elf blah.asm -o blah.o
$ gcc -o blah blah.c blah.o
$ ./blah
next char:o
next char:o
next char:o
next char:k
next char:

$
$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.09.08 compiled on Apr 30 2011

$ uname -a
Linux violet-313 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 17:34:21 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Hope it works for you ;)

Comment: Something like what i changed in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

On linux x86 the first function parameter is in `ecx`. The printf format for printing a pointer is `"%p"`.

So something along

```
    ...
    FORMAT: db '%p', 10, 0 ; to break the line 10, 0
processdata:
    mov eax, [esp+4]
    push eax
    push format
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ret
```

should work, assuming the rest of your code is correct and your are using gcc's calling convention.

This is assuming that the pointer you want to print is on the stack.

The reason for the crash is probably that you push 12 bytes on the stack, but correct the stack pointer by only 8.

Comment: it returns some messy characters and segmentation fault. what is the gcc's calling convention?

Comment: Sorry, but how i do that, first time on assembly language

Comment: Yes, I see. The whole routine you wrote is crap.

Comment: Dont work, thanks for the help, i'll search more on the internet

Comment: It worked, i changed to %s and it showed all the string, how can i show only one of the chars, i need to compare one by one, but if i printf "%c" or %d it prints a messed char or a messed number

Comment: Use `"%c"` and call the function with `processdata(processString[0])`

Comment: But if i need to increment, can i do that?